# OpenTripPlanner Server won't start

Tags: java, opentripplanner

I was following this tutorial to learn how to setup and run OpenTripPlanner : https://github.com/marcusyoung/otp-tutorial/blob/master/intro-otp.pdf

Everything goes well, until I want to start the server with this command : 
`java -Xmx2G -jar otp.jar --router current --graphs graphs --server`

I get this on loop : [image]

http://localhost:8080 shows nothing, tried the next command that selects different ports but the same thing happens.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update Java on my machine.

Comment: from which java version to?